# Cambiar color a mi tabbedPage en xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Alguien sabe como puedo cambiar el color de mi tabbedPage en Xamarin forms, lo quiero tener del mismo color del Navigation Bar que tengo. **La siguiente imagen es un ejemplo de como lo quiero, solo falta cambiar el color del Tabbed Page.**

[image: Tabbed Page ejemplo]

Answer (score 2):

## Solución

Lo único que necesitas hacer es cambiar el código de color del atributo `colorPrimary` ubicado en el archivo `styles.xml` de tu proyecto Android (Resources > values).

```
<item name="colorPrimary">#TU_CODIGO_HEX</item>
```

## Explicación

Por defecto, tanto **la barra de navegación** como **la barra de tabs** en Android, toman como color de fondo el `colorPrimary` definido en tu archivo `styles.xml`. Los archivos `Tabbar.axml` y `Toolbar.axml`, ubicados en Resources > layout, tienen enlazada su propiedad `android:background` a dicho color. Verifica que tienen esto:

```
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
```

Y esos son los layouts que toma Xamarin.Forms para renderizar dichos controles. Fíjate en el `MainActivity.cs` que tienes 2 líneas así:

```
TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos opciones, la primera es usar un [custom render](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/) donde básicamente tomas la clase base (en este caso `TabbedPage`) y modificas la propiedad que necesitas.

La otra opción que tienes (solo para android) es usar temas, en los foros de xamarin puedes tomar como base el [siguiente código](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/28113/custom-tabbedrenderer-to-set-tab-text-color-on-android)

En el [blog de Xamarin](https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/), James Montemagno tiene exactamente el estilo para modificar el estilo de los tabs en android para Xamarin forms

Answer (score 0):

**Ejemplo:**

```
  <TabbedPage //todo lo demás 
BarBackgroundColor="{StaticResource ColorAzul}" 
    BarTextColor="{StaticResource ColorBlanco}" >
```

BarBackgroundColor y BarTextColor son propiedades de TabbedPage, con la primera puede cambiar el color del tab y con la segunda el texto de los tabs.

**En la App.xaml**

```
   <Application>
   <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

    //aqui meteras todo lo que se refiere a color, estilo y demás...
    //es de gran ayuda ya que te ayuda a tener todo de una manera más organizada
    <!-- Colores-->
    <Color x:Key="ColorAzul">#2196F3</Color>
    <Color x:Key="ColorBlanco">#FFFFFF</Color>

  </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
    </Application>
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Luis. Dado que es tu primera publicación, te recomiendo que agregues más información sobre cómo esto resuelve el problema que indica el OP y quizás proveer un poco más de detalle sobre los cambios que indicas. Por ejemplo, qué significan los atributos `BarBackgroundColor` y `BarTextColor` y quizás una recomendación de colores a usar, como un código que funcione.

Answer (score 0):

okay Te entiendo.

```
        BarBackgroundColor="Aqui pornes el color que quieras. "
```

Esta es la propiedad para cambiar el color de la barra de un tabbedPage.

la usas desde la cabezera. del taggedPage..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:App.Views;assembly=App"
            x:Class="App.Views.Test"
            Title="TestBar"            
            BarBackgroundColor="White"
            BarTextColor="#339966">

</TabbedPage>
```